# Enviar formulário para E-mail

Tags: php, html, email

```
<form method="post" action="phpmailer.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome">
    <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

PHPMailer

```
<?php
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '*********@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '*********';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                   // tls
    $mail->Port = 465;                           // 587

    $mail->setFrom('exemplo@exemplo.com', 'Exemplo');
    $mail->addAddress('exemplo@exemplo.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('exemplo@exemplo.com', 'Exemplo');

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Assunto';
    $mail->Body    = 'Mensagem';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Mensagem';

    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else{
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
?>
```

Erro

```
smtp error: failed to connect to server: network is unreachable (101)
```

Está sendo utilizada a versão mais recente da biblioteca.

O GMail já está configurado para aplicativos menos seguros.

Comment: Por favor, explique o que você está tentando fazer com esse form e esse código PHP

Comment: Preciso enviar os dados do formulário para um E-mail do GMail. No caso estou utilizando a biblioteca PHPMailer. Mas obtenho o seguinte erro: smtp error: failed to connect to server: network is unreachable (101). - Estou utilizando a versão mais recente da biblioteca e já configurei o GMail para aplicativos menos seguros.

Comment: o erro pode estar no seu servidor de hospedagem, ele pode estar bloqueando o acesso ao servidor SMTP de uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523285/phpmailer-and-gmail-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-network-is-unreacha#answer-20545650)

Comment: Da uma olhada ai nos comentários, vai te dar um sentido.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/149

Comment: Eu estive com dor de cabeça com SMTP do Gmail esses dias, mas o cliente era um software para Linux e não PHP. Se o problema não for na sua hospedagem, provavelmente vai ter que usar a porta 587 mesmo com SSL.

Comment: O problema pode estar no servidor